# Cakephp 3.7 - Entity accessible property element changed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

The `$_accessible` property for the db column of `user_id` key & value are being changed to `(int)0 => false` from `'user_id' => true` and I don't know how or why. Therefore, the `user_id` in the form data is being ignored and is not part of the patched entity.

Specs: CakePHP 3.7 on Windows Server 2012 with MySQL 8.

The Warehouses entity was initially created via bake without the associated `user_id`, but with the associated `company_id`. I am & was able to save/edit records when `company_id` is populated. I then manually added the user_id field to DB and all related Warehouses & Users files.

I've got validation logic that works appropriately to determine if `company_id` or `user_id` is populated. But since the `user_id` field is being changed on the $_accessible property, my record is created without the user_id value when I am attempting to create such a record.

I have other tables in my app with similar setups working perfectly well (table.id, table.jobs_id, table.onsite_id) where job_id would be populated or onsite_is would be populated. But never both empty or both populated.

DB Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `warehouses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `create_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modify_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `costed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`name`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

WarehousesTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
  {
      parent::initialize($config);
      $this->setTable('warehouses');
      $this->setDisplayField('name');
      $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
      $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
      $this->hasMany('Inventory', ['foreignKey' => 'warehouse_id']);
      $this->belongsTo('Companies', ['foreignKey' => 'company_id']);
      $this->belongsTo('Users', ['foreignKey' => 'user_id']);
  }
```

Warehouse.php

```
protected $_accessible = [
      'name' => true,
      'company_id' => true,
      'user_id' > true,
      'created' => true,
      'create_user' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'modify_user' => true,
      'costed' => true,
      'deleted' => true,
      'inventory' => true 
  ];
```

UsersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
  {
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->setTable('users');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('Companies');
    $this->setDisplayField('full_name');
    $this->hasMany('Uploads', ['foreignKey' => 'user_id']);
   $this->hasMany('Warehouses', ['foreignKey' => 'user_id']);
  }
```

add.ctp

```
<div class="warehouses form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create($warehouse);?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Warehouse</legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('what_needed', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => ['0' => 'Internal', 'C' => 'Customer', 'T' => 'Field Tech'], 'label' => 'Warehouse for internal, Customer or Field Tech?'));
        echo $this->Form->control('company_id', array('empty' => 'Select a company', 'options' => $companies, 'label' => 'Company'));
        echo $this->Form->control('user_id', array('empty' => 'Select a user', 'options' => $users, 'label' => 'User'));
        echo $this->Form->control('costed', array('label'=>'Is Warehouse Costed?'));
        echo "</fieldset>";
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php 
echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
</div>
```

In the Warehouses controller add method, I've debugged the ->newEntity(), the ->request->getData() and the ->patchEntity(). That information is below.

Thanks in advance for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

```
debug($warehouse = $this->Warehouses->newEntity());
object(App\Model\Entity\Warehouse) {

    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'company_id' => true,
        (int) 0 => false, //*why is this false? what happened to user_id*
        'created' => true,
        'create_user' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'modify_user' => true,
        'costed' => true,
        'deleted' => true,
        'inventory' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Warehouses'

}

debug($this->request->getData());
[
    'name' => 'Blah Blah Trunk',
    'what_needed' => 'T',
    'company_id' => '',
    'user_id' => '5',
    'costed' => '0'
]

debug($this->Warehouses->patchEntity($warehouse, $this->request->getData()));
object(App\Model\Entity\Warehouse) {

    'name' => 'Blah Blah Trunk',
    'costed' => false,
    'create_user' => (int) 2,
    'modify_user' => (int) 2,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'company_id' => true,
        (int) 0 => false, //*why is this false? what happened to user_id*
        'created' => true,
        'create_user' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'modify_user' => true,
        'costed' => true,
        'deleted' => true,
        'inventory' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'costed' => true,
        'create_user' => true,
        'modify_user' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Warehouses'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your typo: **'user_id' > true**

```
protected $_accessible = [
      'name' => true,
      'company_id' => true,
      'user_id' > true, // <---------- you have typo here, must be 'user_id' => true
      'created' => true,
      'create_user' => true,
      'modified' => true,
      'modify_user' => true,
      'costed' => true,
      'deleted' => true,
      'inventory' => true 
  ];
```

You can easy detect errors in your code using some scripts, like cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer, phpstan,..

```
composer require --dev cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer
composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan
composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules
```

Add in your composer scripts like:

```
"scripts": {
    "cs-check": "phpcs --colors -p --ignore=*.js --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP config/ src/ plugins/ tests/",
    "cs-fix": "phpcbf --colors --ignore=*.js --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP config/ src/ plugins/ tests/",
    "phpstan": "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse src plugins --level=0",
    "test": "phpunit --colors=always"
},
```

Run from terminal / console:

- `composer cs-check` for check code style errors
- `composer cs-fix` for quick fix some code style errors
- `composer phpstan` for analysing code, start with --level 0

Comment: Sigh. I feel so stupid. The lamest and most easiest to correct. Thank you for the suggestions as well. I will definitely look into them.